# Is it possible to combine two citestyles in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

so I have this problem, when I use the

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=inline, bibstyle=alphabetic,  citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

I get for `\footnote{\cite{somebook}}` the output:

[image: how it is]

but I would like to have it like this:

[image: how it should be]

so it should be:

> author, year, short symbol, page

of course I can say

```
\footnote{Vgl. \citeauthor{book}, \citeyear{book}, \cite{book} p. xxx}
```

but I was hoping there would be a more elegant way?

Furthermore not every entry (the ones from the internet) has a year and I solved it with the note.

My config is made like this:

```
% !TEX root =  master.tex

%       LANGUAGE SETTINGS AND FONT ENCODING 
%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % German language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}    % correct quotes using \enquote{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{float}


%\usepackage[english]{babel}   % For english language
%\usepackage{csquotes}  % Richtiges Setzen der Anführungszeichen mit \enquote{}

% Zwei eigene Befehle zum Setzen von Autor und Titel. Ausserdem werden die PDF-Informationen richtig gesetzt.
\newcommand{\TitelDerArbeit}[1]{\def\DerTitelDerArbeit{#1}\hypersetup{pdftitle={#1}}}
\newcommand{\AutorDerArbeit}[1]{\def\DerAutorDerArbeit{#1}\hypersetup{pdfauthor={#1}}}
\newcommand{\Firma}[1]{\def\DerNameDerFirma{#1}}
\newcommand{\Kurs}[1]{\def\DieKursbezeichnung{#1}}

% Correct superscripts 
\usepackage{fnpct}

%       CALCULATIONS
%
\usepackage{calc} % Used for extra space below footsepline

%       BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS
%
% Uncomment the next three lines for author-year-style with footnotes (Chicago)
%\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=footnote, style=authortitle, dashed=false]{biblatex}%vorher authoryear
%Use Author-Year-Cites with footnotes
%\AdaptNoteOpt\footcite\multfootcite   %will add  separators if footcite is called multiple consecutive times 
%\AdaptNoteOpt\autocite\multautocite % will add  separators if autocite is called multiple consecutive times

% Uncomment the next line for IEEE-style 
%\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=inline, style=ieee]{biblatex}  % Use IEEE-Style (e.g. [1])

% Uncomment the next line for apa-style 
%\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=inline, style=apa]{biblatex}   % Use apa-Style

% Uncomment the next line for alphabetic style 
\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=inline, bibstyle=alphabetic,  citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
%\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

% Use alphabetic style: alphabetic (e.g. [TGK12])
% Don't fall back on other year fields if there is no year, use
% "nodate" string
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{pubstate}
  \field{date}
  \literal{o. D.}
}
% Uncomment the next two lines vor Harvard-Style 
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}    
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{  %Change u.a. to et al. (german only!)
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

%%%für die Umbrüche der URLs im Literaturverzeichnis
\apptocmd{\UrlBreaks}{\do\f\do\m}{}{}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}% Kleinbuchstaben
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}% Großbuchstaben

\setlength{\bibparsep}{\parskip}    %add some space between biblatex entries in the bibliography
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}   %Add file bibliography.bib as biblatex resource

%       FOOTNOTES 
%
% Count footnotes over chapters
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{tablefootnote} %damit Fußnoten in Tabellen richtig angezeigt werden

%   ACRONYMS
%%%
%%% WICHTIG: Installieren Sie das neueste Acronyms-Paket!!!
%%%
\makeatletter
\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}

\@ifpackagelater{acronym}{2015/03/20}
  {%
    \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{\acsfont{#1}}}}
  }%
  {%
  }%
\makeatother

%Figure

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abbildung}
\renewcommand*\listoflofentryname{\figurename}
\BeforeStartingTOC[lof]{\renewcommand*\autodot{:}}

%Table


\renewcommand*\listoflotentryname{\tablename}
\BeforeStartingTOC[lot]{\renewcommand*\autodot{:}}




%       LISTINGS

\usepackage[final]{listings}    %Format Listings properly
\usepackage{color} %für das Styling in anderen Farben
\usepackage{scrhack}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quelltext}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Quelltextverzeichnis}


\newcommand\listoflolentryname\lstlistingname
\BeforeStartingTOC[lol]{\renewcommand*\autodot{:}}


\lstset{numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    literate= %für die Umlaute in Listings
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {~}{{\textasciitilde}}1
}
    
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} 
\lstdefinestyle{stylePython}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},       
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=L,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
    language=Python,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue},
    morekeywords={with, as}
}

%       EXTRA PACKAGES
\usepackage{graphicx} % use various graphics formats
\usepackage[german]{varioref}   % nicer references \vref
\usepackage{caption}    %better Captions
\usepackage{booktabs} %nicer Tabs
\usepackage{array}
%\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{setspace} %für Zeilenabstand

%       ALGORITHMS
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Algorithmenverzeichnis }
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithmus}


%       FONT SELECTION: Entweder Latin Modern oder Times / Helvetica
\usepackage{lmodern} %Latin modern font
%\usepackage{mathptmx}  %Helvetica / Times New Roman fonts (2 lines)
%\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet} %Helvetica / Times New Roman fonts (2 lines)

%PAGE HEADER / FOOTER
%Warning: There are some redefinitions throughout the master.tex-file!  DON'T CHANGE THESE REDEFINITIONS!
\RequirePackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\pnumfont}{\upshape\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\upshape\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\footfont}{\upshape\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
\clearscrheadfoot

%\ifoot[\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}Anton Zinn]{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}Anton Zinn}
\ohead[\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}\pagemark]{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}\pagemark}



%       HYPERREF
%
\usepackage[
    hidelinks=true % keine roten Markierungen bei Links
]{hyperref} %am Ende laden, ansonsten kommt es zu Fehlern

\makeatletter %damit Weiterleitung ins Glossar auf richtige Zeile erfolgt
 \newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother
```

and the mastertex like this:

```
%   ACHTUNG: Für das Erstellen des Literaturverzeichnisses wird das modernere Paket biblatex
%            in Kombination mit biber verwendet -- nicht mehr das ältere BibTex!
%            Bitte stellen Sie ggf. Ihre TeX-Umgebung
%            entsprechend ein (z.B. TeXStudio: Einstellungen --> Erzeugen --> Standard Bibliographieprogramm: biber)
%
%bei TexMaker: Optionen -> TexMaker konfigurieren -> bei Bib(la)Tex muss biber.exe ausgewählt werden(befindet sich bei MikTex im Ordner)

\documentclass[
    12pt,
    BCOR=5mm,
    DIV=12,
    headinclude=on,
    footinclude=off,
    parskip=half,
    bibliography=totoc,
    listof=entryprefix,
    toc=listof,
    pointlessnumbers,
    plainfootsepline]{scrreprt}
    
    \oddsidemargin = 0pt %für Seitenrand links kleiner
    \marginparsep = 16pt %für Seitenrand rechts größer

%   Konfigurationsdatei einziehen
\input{formale_einstellungen/config}

\begin{document}


%% BITTE GEBEN SIE HIER DEN TITEL UND DIE AUTORIN / DEN AUTOR DER ARBEIT AN!
%% DIESE INFORMATIONEN _MÜSSEN_ GESETZT SEIN, UM TITELBLATT, ABSTRACT UND
%% EIGENSTÄNDIGKEITSERKLÄRUNG AUTOMATISCH ANZUPASSEN!
\TitelDerArbeit{Evaluation verschiedener Datenbanken für die DAME der OFD}
\AutorDerArbeit{Sarah Übele}
\Firma{Oberfinanzdirektion Karlsruhe (LZfD)}
\Kurs{WI2019 Kurs C}

\onehalfspacing %1,5-zeiliger Abstand zwischen allen Zeilen

\input{formale_einstellungen/titlepage}

\pagenumbering{Roman} % Römische Seitennummerierung
\normalfont

%--------------------------------
% Verzeichnisse - nicht benötige Verzeichnisse bitte auskommentieren / löschen.
%--------------------------------




%   Sperrvermerk
\input{formale_einstellungen/nondisclosurenotice}
\thispagestyle{empty}

%   Kurzfassung
%\input{formale_einstellungen/abstract}
%\thispagestyle{empty}


%   Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\tableofcontents
{
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}} 
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
}

%   Abkürzungsverzeichnis (siehe Datei acronyms.tex!)
\input{formale_einstellungen/acronyms}
\ohead{Acronyms} % Neue Header-Definition
%\ohead{\pagemark}

%   Vorwort
%\input{vorwort}

%   Abbildungsverzeichnis
\listoffigures

%   Tabellenverzeichnis
\listoftables




%   Glossar
\input{formale_einstellungen/Glossar}

%--------------------------------
% Start des Textteils der Arbeit
%--------------------------------
\clearpage
\ihead{\chaptername~\thechapter} % Neue Header-Definition (inner header)
%\ohead{\headmark} % Neue Header-Definition (outer header)
\ohead{\pagemark}
\pagenumbering{arabic}  % Arabische Seitenzahlen

%   Einleitung
\input{PJ1/Einleitung}

%   KAPITEL 2
\input{PJ1/Kapitel2}

%   KAPITEL 3
\input{PJ1/Kapitel3}

%   KAPITEL 4
\input{PJ1/Kapitel4}

% Der Anhang beginnt hier - jedes Kapitel wird alphabetisch aufgezählt. (Anhang A, B usw.)
%\appendix
%\ihead{\appendixname~\thechapter} % Neue Header-Definition

% appendix.tex einziehen
%\input{formale_einstellungen/appendix}

%Beigabenverzeichnis
%\input{beigaben}
%\ihead{Beigaben}


%Literaturverzeichnis
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\ihead{Literatur}
 %Standard aus Vorlage
%\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, type=book, title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=online, title={Elektronische Quellen}]
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, type=article, title={Artikel}]

%   Listingsverzeichnis
\lstlistoflistings

%   Algorithmenverzeichnis
%\listofalgorithms


% Ehrenwörtliche Erklärung ewerkl.tex einziehen
\input{formale_einstellungen/ewerkl}


\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

so does anyone has an idea?

an entry without a year looks like this:

```
@online{oraclevarianten,
    author = {Oracle},
    title = {Oracle Database Editions},
    note = {(o\adddot~D\adddot)},
    url = {https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm#DBLIC109},
    urldate = {2020-07-30},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Not really related to your question, but `bibstyle=alphabetic,  citestyle=alphabetic` can be reduced to the shorter `style=alphabetic,`. Likewise `\footnote{\cite{oraclevarianten}}` could be `\footcite{oraclevarianten}` or - even better -  with `autocite=footnote,` instead of `autocite=inline,` just `\autocite{oraclevarianten}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That citation style looks a bit redundant. A simple author-year style would probably be as informative and would not need the additional label.

Anyway, here's how you could go about implementing it. Since the desired output is very different from what `style=alphabetic,` normally generates, we need to rewrite some bibmacros. Below I picked new names and mapped them to `\autocite` (as suggested in my comment under the question), but you could also re-use cite if you wanted to.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\DeclareDelimFormat[doublecite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{    test {\iffieldundef{year}}
              and test {\iffieldundef{endyear}}}
    {\bibstring{nodate}}
    {\printdate}}

\newbibmacro*{doublecite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelalpha}%
      \printfield{extraalpha}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\doublecite}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{doublecite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\doublecites}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
  {\doublecite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{doublecite}{\doublecite}{\doublecites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=doublecite,}


\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}

\setlength{\bibparsep}{\parskip}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{oraclevarianten,
  author  = {Oracle},
  title   = {Oracle Database Editions},
  url     = {https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm#DBLIC109},
  urldate = {2020-07-30},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[Vgl.][380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{oraclevarianten}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Vgl. Sigfridsson und Ryde, 1998, [SR98], S. 380.]

---

*edit* in response to the comments.

When you rearrange the bibmacro, you also need to take into account the `\setunit` lines.

If you want different date formats in the citation and the bibliography,  `labeldate` comes in handy again. (Until https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/863 is resolved anyway.)

There already is a space between the 'o.' and 'D.' but it's a small space (`\,`), you can redefine the string to get a larger normal space.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  labeldateparts,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  nodate    = {{}o.\adddotspace D\adddot},
}

\DeclareDelimFormat[doublecite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{    test {\iffieldundef{year}}
              and test {\iffieldundef{endyear}}}
    {\bibstring{nodate}}
    {\printdate}}

\newbibmacro*{doublecite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelalpha}%
      \printfield{extraalpha}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlabeldate}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\doublecite}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{doublecite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\doublecites}[\iffootnote\mkbibbrackets\mkbibfootnote]
  {\doublecite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{doublecite}{\doublecite}{\doublecites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=doublecite,}


\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}

\setlength{\bibparsep}{\parskip}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{oraclevarianten,
  author  = {Oracle},
  title   = {Oracle Database Editions},
  url     = {https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm#DBLIC109},
  urldate = {2020-07-30},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[Vgl.][380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{oraclevarianten}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are awesome it does exactly what I want. But I idiot told you the sequence wrong. It should have been: ++author, short symbol, year, page++ I changed the sequence in the code, but now there isn`t a comma after the short symbol. Also there isn´t space between the o. D., it´s written o.D also is it possible, when the date is dd-mm-yyyy to just print the year in the footnote? Tank you so much in advance moewe.

Comment: @sarahlein See the edit, please.

Comment: Yes now everything works exactly as it should. Thanks so much for your help moewe :D You relly helped me out :)